# Parallel processing of small functions in the cloud

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, cloud, starcluster

I'm having a few million/billion (10^9) data-input-sets, that need to be processed.
They are quiet small < 1kB. And they need about 1 second to be processed.

I have read a lot about Apache Hadoop, Map Reduce and StarCluster.
But I am not sure what the most efficient and fastest way is, to process it?

I am thinking of using Amazon EC2 or a similar cloud service.

Comment: Hadoop and MapReduce are pretty adaptable but they are definitely better at some things. Are you willing/able to code? What languages do you know? What kind of processing do you need to do on the data?

Comment: I guess I could have just looked at your profile ;)

Comment: @PaulM The language does not matter, I know Python, Java, Ruby, C, C++ so I will (hopefully) be able to learn it :) The input is a small String and it will be processed like a sha512 hash - at least it is some hash-like function - but other details I am not allowed to provide.

Comment: Sounds like you're working on a rainbow table / password cracker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider something like [Amazon EMR](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/) which takes care of a lot of the plumbing with Hadoop. If your just looking to code something quickly, hadoop streaming, hive and PIG are all good tools for getting started with hadoop w/out requring you to know all of the ins and outs of MapReduce.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added some details in the question's comment. Can you recommend some special method (streaming/hive/pig)? Sorry, that I can not provide some more details.

Comment: In that case, I would try using hadoop streaming on Amazon EMR. Hadoop streaming let's you write MapReduce programs like unix pipelines using your language of choice. The tradeoff is a performance penalty that may or may not be meaningful to you. Amazon EMR saves you the trouble of spinning up a cluster. You do have to pay for Amazon EMR.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a deeper look at it.